# Would a Synthesist summoner have access to their Eidolon's feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner

I am thinking of playing as a Synthesist summoner but I can't find a source telling me whether I get my Eidolon's feats or if those feats are only used should I use split forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist/) archetype special ability **fused eidolon** changes much about the chained [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/)'s eidolon. Among those changes is that the fused eidolon "has no skills or feats of its own." Thus there are simply *no* feats for a synthesist summoner to gain from its fused eidolon.